# Using Google App Engine's send_mail in Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use GAE's `send_mail` in Django:

```
 from google.appengine.api import mail
 mail.send_mail(sender=x,to=y,subject='Test Mail',body='Test',)
```

And I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named google.appengine.api

Comment: did you installed the sdk? which version of python are you using

Comment: Yes, Python 2.7.12.

Comment: then i guess the sdk was not properly installed or the program is not getting the path

Comment: @Exprator thank you